# How to restore activity after being stopped?

Tags: android, android-activity, restore

The scenario is like this:
I have an activity that starts a thread (through AsyncTask). I get the state correctly saved and restored when changing screen orientation (with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState), the thread is stopped in onStop(). But if I "minimize" (or change app) I get my state saved but NOT restored. What can I do?

-- Edit: Solved
Thank you guys, I had found many similar answers but the problems were kinda more elaborated, I thought that a simple question could lead to another solutions but I guess I'm stuck with those two options.
onRestoreInstanceState and SharedPreferences.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the rules for when the state is saved and restored depend on situations that you can't easily predict, I'd recommend using a different approach. Using shared preferences is probably the easiest. Here's a [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to the storage options reference page that shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Bro, there are two ways to resolve it. First one is very easy. Use `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` to maintaint your activity. 2nd method is to use SharedPreferences :)